# Creation of dependend select

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, select

I created a jsp that will include two seletcts and one depends on the other.
In the first are city names:

```
<div class="container p-5">
<form action="/addFlat" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">City</label>
        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
            <c:forEach items="${cities}" var="cities">
                <option value="${cities.id}">${cities.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>

        </select>
    </div>
```

I want the second to display street names that depend on the first.
I used hibernate to create tables.
City:

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Street:

```
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;
```